# how to download applications from https://apps.ubuntu.com

Tags: software-installation

i am trying to download a image editor from https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/

but as i click on "available on software center" a window opens to choose application,

which application should i choose and from where(location of application).

And how to install application after its download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Click on choose an application

[image]

- Go to `/usr/bin` and click on `software-center` and select open.

[image]

- Now the `software-center` will be added to the application list.

[image]

- Then click on the software-center and press ok to download and install gimp.

Comment: the unasked and unanswered bit is why it's not set to do it - unless it's not Ubuntu I suppose

Answer (score 0):

just point the path to

`/usr/bin/software-center`

ubuntu software center will open the link it'll download the software and install it

an even better option is open your dash type software center and in the search type gimp now press install done :)